# How to convert Array of dictionaries [[String:String]] to []

Tags: arrays

The getSystemInspectors()->[Inspectors] which is of [[String:String]] type. I want to convert dictionary of type [[String:String]] to array of [Inspectors] Any help is appreciated.

```
func getSystemInspectors() -> [Inspector] {
        let systemUsers = self.getSystemUsers()

        return []
    }


struct Inspector {
    var id: Int
    var firstName: String
    var middleName: String
    var lastName:String

    init(id: Int, firstName: String, middleName: String, lastName:String) {
        self.id = id
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.middleName = middleName
        self.lastName = lastName
    }

    init(_ dict: [String:Any]) {
        self.id = dict[InspectorConstants.id] as? Int ?? 0
        self.firstName = dict[InspectorConstants.firstName] as? String ?? ""
        self.middleName = dict[InspectorConstants.middleName] as? String ?? ""
        self.lastName = dict[InspectorConstants.lastName] as? String ?? ""
    }

    func toDictionary() -> [String:Any] {
        return [
            InspectorConstants.id: id,
            InspectorConstants.firstName: firstName.trim(),
            InspectorConstants.middleName: middleName.trim(),
            InspectorConstants.lastName: lastName.trim()
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the constructor for `Inspector` look like?

Comment: I added the code